# How to pass variable to external js in magento 2

Tags: magento2, prototype-js

In magento 1

we can call this prototype function in phtml for example

```
function ABC(){
     var a = '<?php echo $a;?>'
    alert(a);
 }
```

but in magento 2 we can not add this type of function in phtml,for that we have to create `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'exam': 'js/example',
    }
}
};
```

like this and example.js

```
 function ABC(){

    alert(a);
 }
```

in phtml

```
require(['jquery','exam'], function($){
    var a= <?php echo $a; ?>;
});
```

I am trying to pass variable like this but its not working,how to pass variable from phtml to external js in magento 2

Answer (score 25):

There are two ways to include javascript from the template in Magento 2: the `<script type="text/x-magento-init">` and the `data-mage-init` attribute. Either way can be used to pass data to the script within the json definition.
For example, using the x-magento-init script tag, in the template you have:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "js/example": {
                "a": "<?php echo 'Hello from template' ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And in the JS file, you have:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        console.log(config); // will output {a: "Hello from template"}
        alert(config.a); // would be equal to alert("Hello from template");
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using this code, but my alert is popping up twice, however if I write an alert before "return function (config) {" it pops up only one, I can't find why the alerts inside "return function (config) {" are coming twice.

Comment: Great info, but how would I gain access to the data in the config object from another js file? For example, if I sent the above data – '"a": "<?php echo 'Hello from template' ?>" to a js/model/example.js file, how would I then pull that data into a view/sample.js file? Many thanks!

Comment: Trying to pass data around between different .js files seems like it probably wouldn't work. You could just pass the data to both files' configs in the template. Or, if you have some data you want to be accessible to various js files, you could use Magento's 'private content 'mechanism: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html which is what is used internally for the mini-cart, customer data, compare products, etc.

Comment: As a side note, if you try this and it doesn't work make sure you are using `define` and not `require`. This doesn't work when using `require`.

Comment: @ Aaron Allen Very Good answer

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the variable by using js Widget

Vendor: **Rbj** Module: **DemoWidget**
**app/code/Rbj/DemoWidget/view/frontend/layout/demo_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="demo.page" template="Rbj_DemoWidget::magento-widget.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**app/code/Rbj/DemoWidget/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "myCustomWidget": "Rbj_DemoWidget/js/my-custom-widget"
        } 
    }
};
```

**app/code/Rbj/DemoWidget/view/frontend/web/js/my-custom-widget.js**

```
define([
'jquery',
'jquery/ui'
], function($){
    $.widget('mage.myCustomWidget', {
        options: {
            abcd: 1,
            passvalue:'test'
        },
        /**
         * Widget initialization
         * @private
         */
         _create: function() {
            alert(this.options.passvalue);  // custom message
            alert(this.options.abcd); // 123
        }
    });
return $.mage.myCustomWidget;
});
```

**app/code/Rbj/DemoWidget/view/frontend/templates/magento-widget.phtml**

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="secondary">
        Widget Example using Magento 2
    </div>
<div> 
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    ".maindiv": {
        "myCustomWidget": {
            "passvalue": "custom message",
            "abcd": 123
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

*Vote this answer up if it helps.*

Answer (score 0):

## data-mage-init Example

```
<div data-mage-init='{"js/example": { "message": "<?= 'Hello from template' ?>"}}'>
    <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Show Info')) ?>"
       class="action action-info ral-surcharge-info"
    >
        <i class="fas fa-info"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        console.log(config); // will output {a: "Hello from template"}
        alert(config.message); // would be equal to alert("Hello from template");
    }
});
```