# How to get current currency symbol in magento 2 js

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, currency

> I want to use current currency symbol in custom module Js.

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko',
'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, component) {
    'use strict';
    return component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this._render();
        },
        _render:function(){
            var self = this;
            console.log("need current currency symbol here.");
        },
        defaults: {
            template: 'Namespace_Modulename/product/view/price',
        },
    });
});
```

> Any suggestion would be appreciated.
>
> Thanks

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer sorry, but if you have access to the currency symbol you can pass it through to your JS file. Check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100787/how-to-pass-variable-to-external-js-in-magento-2) on how to do that

Comment: Thanks for your answer @BenCrook I have passed currency symbol through Json and now I can access this in Js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this first you have to create a block file as below:

```
<?php
class Customclass{
    protected $_currency;
    public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,
    ){       
        $this->_currency = $currency;
    }

    public function getStoreCurrencySymbol(){
        return $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
    }
}
```

In it's template you need to call above function and pass the value to your js file as below:

```
<script>
    window.getCurrency = {
            "getCurrencySymbol":<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $block->getStoreCurrencySymbol(); ?>
        };
</script>
<div class="my-class">
    <div id="my-id" data-bind="scope: 'curency-symbol'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#decoration-tier-price": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout(); ?>
            }
        }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

create your js file as below where you will get your current currency symbol.

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko',
'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, component) {
  'use strict';

  return component.extend({
    initialize: function () {
      this._super();
      this._render();
    },
    _render: function () {
      var self = this;
      var getCurency = window.getCurrency;
      console.log(getCurency.getCurrencySymbol)
    },
    defaults: {
      template: 'namespace_modulename/template/path',
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i told you one think you have get currency in store collection then store any varible then this variable you use in script tags 
same like this 
example:-`var num = <?php echo $num ?>;`
i hope you are understand this way think and do this way :)
and current store currency please you refrence this website
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-currency-code-currency-symbol-currency-rate/